# Удаленный доступ к объектам в Android

Tags: java, android, интерфейс, callback, rpc

Есть 2 приложения. Оба приложения имеют определение интерфейса `ICollback`. `Приложение 1` реализует интерфейс в классе `CallbackImpl`, а `приложение 2` должно зарегистрировать `callback` и вызвать методы. Вопрос в том, как `приложение 2` может получить объект `CallbackImpl` для регистрации `callback`? Передать его через `Bundle` не получиться, т.к. `приложение 2` ничего не знает про имплементацию.

Какие есть способы решения проблемы?

Comment: Получилось через AIDL. Method 3 по ссылке: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android

Answer (score 0):

Решение с Callback-ами работать не будет, никакие данные между двумя приложениями никогда не передаются в рантайме, тем более исполняемый код. Для реализации того, что вы хотите сделать, нужно использовать Intent.

Вы должны в приложении-получателе указать в манифесте то, что вы хотите перехватывать интенты "вот такого типа"(придумайте себе свой) и отправлять их вот в эту активити(описвание перехватываемых интентов происходит внутри тега activity). В самой активити в onCreate вы получаете интент через getIntent и вытаскиваете из него сериализованные записанные в строку данные.

В приложении-отправителе создаем интент с вашим типом, наполняем данными и отправляем в космос, то есть в систему, а система уже поймет кому ваш интент отдавать и, собственно, отдаст

Начните с [официальных](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters?hl=ru) страничек, для простых вещей примеров оттуда хватит

Comment: А почему AIDL не подходит?

Comment: Я с ними не работал, не скажу прям что не подойдут, но там вроде немного другая история, и они опять же служат для передачи сериализованных данных, а не для передачи поведения.

Comment: Ну а если передавать данные или поведение, а ссылку на объект?!

Comment: У вас два разных приложения с разделенной памятью. Два участка памяти с одним адресом в разных приложениях расположгаются в разных местах оперативной памяти средствами операционной системы. Вы можете передать адрес как число в другую  программу, но там оно не имеет смысла, потому что у другой программы по этому же адресу лежит что-то другое. А скопировать данные из области памяти одной программы в область памяти другой нельзя никак. Только передавать средствами операционной системы, которые допускают лишь примитивы

Comment: @AndrewEfremov, если вы хотите реализовать подключение к службе с помощью `AIDL` - то так и пишите в вопросе. А то интерфейс понятие широкое. Можете исправить вопрос и покурить гайд: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl пока подойдут люди, знающие толк в таких извращениях))) Лично я бы не связывался, а обошёлся обменом данными через `Message`. И офф. гайды тоже рекоммендуют `AIDL` только при необходимости многопоточного доступа к службе

Comment: Приложение 1 общается с приложением 2 как с привязанной службой через механизм Message. Но я не могу передать объект через Bundle. В этом случае Приложение 2 должно обращаться за объектом в Приложение 1?

Comment: Еще раз. Вы никак не передадите объект целиком. И не должны это делать. Если он имеет поведение, которые вы хотите передать - это запрещено с точки зрения безопасности. Если поведения нет, и там только данные - то они могут быть завернуты в json или еще во что-то. Ну на самый край можете записать данные в файл и передать второму приложению путь к файлу. Но объект, созданный в рантайме передавать нельзя. Можете попробовать описать ваш конкретный случай, чтоб мы могли более конкретно подсказать, но маловероятно что ответ изменится

Comment: Живой объект вы не получите никак, только сериализованный на одной стороне и восстановленный на другой. В Андроиде для этого лучше реализовать в нём `Parcelable` и, соответственно копия его класса должна быть в обоих приложениях

Comment: Описание проблемы. Есть наша библиотека и приложение. Библиотека взаимодействует с приложением как с привязанной службой через Messeges. С нашей библиотекой работает стороннее приложение, которое должно передать нашему приложению объект, методы которого мы должны вызывать. Библиотеке оно может передать объект, но как его передать нашему приложению?

Comment: Это не уточнение описания) Скажите зачем вам исполнять чужой код, что вообще безумие

Comment: Получилось через AIDL. Method 3 по ссылке: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android  Всем спасибо!

Comment: Оформите тогда ответом, чтоб следующий, кто заинтересуется вопросом, не мучился поиском в комментах. И все таки, AIDL же ограничен примитивами, верно? Мне просто интересно в какой ситуации лучше передавать интерфейс, выдающий в методах примитивы, чем просто сразу вычисленные примитивы)

Comment: В смысле примитивами? По ссылке в примере создается интерфейс с двумя методами. Методы выполняются в другом процессе.

Comment: В смысле эти методы могу принимать в параметрах только примитивы/строки и возвращать только примитивы/строки

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700225/in-out-inout-in-a-aidl-interface-parameter-value

Comment: in - object is transferred from client to service only used for inputs
    out - object is transferred from client to service only used for outputs.
    inout - object is transferred from client to service used for both inputs and outputs.